# sql create table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I cannot find the syntax error in the following statement:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.statslogsummary as
  (SELECT COUNT(logID) AS userid, logUserID,MAX(logDateTime)
FROM statsLog
GROUP BY logUserID);
```

Tells me "invalid syntax near AS"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE - after is is clear that this is SQL Server:**

```
SELECT COUNT(logID) AS userid, logUserID,MAX(logDateTime) AS maxlogtm
INTO dbo.statslogsummary  
FROM statsLog
GROUP BY logUserID
```

Comment: @user990016 you didn't say which DB you are on, the above works just fine on Oracle... as I see you added a tags saying it is SQL Server... for SQL Server use my updated answer above...

Answer (score 3):

A CREATE TABLE statement shouldn't have a SELECT statement in it.  A CREATE TABLE statement should only be defining the table structure.

If you're trying to create a table by selecting data from another table, you need to use the [Select Into](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp) syntax.

```
SELECT COUNT(logID) AS userid, logUserID,MAX(logDateTime)  AS logDateTime
INTO dbo.statslogsummary  
FROM statsLog
GROUP BY logUserID
```

Comment: You've done away with using the "CREATE TABLE" part of your statement, right?  My entire code snippet will create the table without explicitly using the CREATE TABLE command.  Also, check the link I included (the words "Select INTO") which documents how it works.

Comment: @DavidStratton your statement won't work because the last column (MAX...) doesn't have an alias...

Comment: AHHH Thanks!  Good eye!  Voting you up since you caught that detail amd edited my code.